# Symbian belle emulator browser version

Tags: html, emulation, symbian

I'm testing a web site on symbian_belle_sdk_1.0 emulator, but the installed browser version is too old for me. Alerting the userAgent returns me "NokiaBrowser 7.4.2.4". Is there a way to update the browser to "NokiaBrowser 8.3.1.4" or any other way to test with newer NokiaBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about upgrading browser in emulator, but for other ways to test it: first is, of course, real device. And second option is [Remote device access](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/).